# Requests to third parties (SOAP, Youtube API failing intermittently) on CentosBox

Tags: networking, php, centos

Our new site (LAMP) has been running w/o incident for about a month on a dedicated Centos 6 box at 1and1.

Intermittently (about 10 mins per most hours)  starting last night the server has issues loading external 3rd party resources. For example, for our search which uses hosted data at a third party we access via SOAP, and we have several places where we bring in a youtube API feed. I Hard-coded the youtube stuff so that is no longer an issue, but the inventory search is still bombing out occasionally.

When we check resources - even during one of these "outages" the server seems to be in very good shape, additionally, the site itself responds without issue or delay.

I have contacted 1and1 and they confirm the server looks good, and cannot explain the reasons for the outage other than that it is a "network issue".

Furthermore it hangs whenever I try to connect via sftp or through our mysql client.

Can I safely assume this is a network issue - ie a bad router or something?

site is http://www.rocelec.com

Thanks in advance